# How can I type 's in python

Tags: python

I am trying to pass the name of "Angela's Ashes" in a single bracket like below.

```
href="{{ url_for('cart', name = 'Angela's Ashes')}}"
```

Is there anyway to type in this without creating another variable?

Comment: just escape the character `\'`

Comment: Is that really Python? It looks like a template in HTML.

Comment: Rest in peace Angela

Comment: As far as Python is concerned, that's a valid string. The only problem will be with whatever tries to interpret `url_for`.

Comment: yes. \' works@Mohammad

Answer (score 1):

If this is a HTML template, you can try using double-quotes inside the `{{ }}` - since those are within the template argument, only the template engine will see the quotes and it won't affect the HTML:

`<a href="{{ url_for("cart", name = "Angela's Ashes") }}">`

Comment: this technique is quite valid too, though you'll want want to wrap with triple-quotes `"""` or similar!

Comment: I don't see why you would need triple quotes - if this is an HTML template, the outer quotes belong to the HTML attribute and passed directly to the output, while the inner quotes are parsed by the template system. No triple quotes would be necessary in that case.

Comment: oh, their original example looked like it intended to be valid Python code assigning to the name `href`, but if this appeared in an HTML template it should be successfully replaced

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`html.escape(s, quote=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html), or simply replace
`'` with `&#x27;` where you need it

```py
>>> import html
>>> html.escape("Angela's Ashes")
'Angela&#x27;s Ashes'
```

Other XHMTL escapes can be seen here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference#Examples

(you can also do this for any character, not only special ones, but it will lead to a longer and more confusing document)

```py
>>> html.unescape("&#x61;")
'a'
```